# Read and Write in http response in middleware

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, memorystream, asp.net-core-middleware

What I want to achieve :
I want to set the culture through a middleware attribute and for my login api I want to update the culture if it is not the same as culture that is received through request header.

The Problem :
I am not able to copy the responseBodyMemoryStream to originalResponseBodyStream

What I've tried :
Here I've created a custom set culture attribute using IAsyncResourceFilter

```
public class SetCultureAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
    {
        public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            //Declare needed objects
            var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            string languagePreference = "en-US";
            string headerPreference = string.Empty;

            // Extract the bearer token from the Authorization header
            string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("LanguageCode"))
            {
                headerPreference = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["LanguageCode"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerPreference))
            {
                var culture = headerPreference == Language.English.ToString() ? "en-US" : "ja";
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate and decode the token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

                    // Extract user information from the token's claims

                    // Setting the culture from token
                }
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(languagePreference);
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languagePreference);
            }

            //now for login api we need to update the language for user
            string actionName = context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
            if (actionName.Contains("Userlogin"))
            {
                HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                if (response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                {
                    var originalResponseBodyStream = response.Body;
                    using (var responseBodyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        response.Body = responseBodyMemoryStream;
                        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
                        await next();

                        // Read the response body from the memory stream
                        responseBodyMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        var responseBody = new StreamReader(responseBodyMemoryStream).ReadToEnd();

                        // extract the userId from response
                        dynamic jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                        string userId = jsonResponse?.id;

                        //Update Header preference in userId

                        // Reset the memory stream position and copy it back to the original response body stream
                        responseBodyMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        await responseBodyMemoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBodyStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            await next();
        }
    }
```

Expextations :
To read and write in the response body after the user is authorized

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was pretty straightforward which I could not see then, after adding the response body to original variable

```
var originalResponseBodyStream = response.Body;
```

we should add a try and finally block to avoid crash and in the finally block **Restore the originalResponseStream to the body**

```
// Restore the original response body
   context.HttpContext.Response.Body = originalResponseBodyStream;
```